# Output values from JSON structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Data that function gets from the server:

```
{
   "COLUMNS":[
      "ID",
      "NAME",
      "LASTNAME"
   ],
   "DATA":[
      [
         "1",
         "John",
         "Lewis"
      ],
      [
         "2",
         "Peter",
         "Gabriel"
      ],
      [
         "3",
         "Susan",
         "Smith"
      ]
   ]
}
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#showteams').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
        url: "authenticationService.cfc?method=getAllTeams&returnformat=JSON&queryformat=column",
        dataType: 'json',

        success:function(data) {

            alert('data that function gets from the server:' + '\n' + '\n' + data + '\n' + '\n' + 
            "everything is listed here");

                    $.each(data.DATA, function(i,team){

                        $('#teamList').append('<li><a href="#">' + team + '</a>');
                    });

                }});
            });
            $('#teams').show();
            $('#teamList').fadeIn(1200);
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
</script>
```

while my code actually works, at least in some way it outputs values like this

```
1,John,Lewis
2,Peter,Gabriel
3,Susan,Smith
```

now I would like to make it more flexible, iterate over the data in some other way and display it for example

This is the user firstname: **NAME** lastname: **LASTNAME** with number **ID**

namely
This is the user firstname: **John** lastname: **Lewis** with number **1**
etc

I know it could be done somehow with **for** but can not sort it out, I've tried everything I could think off :( 
I would really appreciate your help on this one especially given javascript is not really my thing.

**EDIT:
now i have an issue on the server side :(
what i am trying to achieve is to output data say
on first click records from 1 to 10
on second click records from 11-20
.etc
on client side jquery code will pass data such as startrow data: { startrow: "1", maxrow: "10" },
in coldfusion component cfloop should do the trick but for some reason I can not return the correct JSON format.I already tried to cfloop over query put data to array as well as to array of struct and than serializeJSON but failed to sort it out.**

Answer (score 0):

`team` is an array, access it's value using array notation and indexes. `team[0]` `team[1]` `team[2]` for id, firstname, lastname

Comment: Thank you for, I was able to sort it out and do a little more:)

Answer (score 0):

The team in the context has a array which inturn is an array .. So you would need to have two loops .. One for the each item array , the other loop is for the items inside the array..
Try this

```
$.each(data.DATA, function(i,team){ 
     $.each( team , function(key , value){
         alert(value)
     });         
 });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Gbrx6/)

Comment: Thank you for, I was able to sort it out :)